# How to imbricate Rails layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

What I would like to do :

One layout `application.html.haml` where I define the common elements to all pages like in the following

```
%html
  %head
    %title
      = @title
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    %header
      .navbar.navbar-fixed-top
        .navbar-inner
          .container
            .pull-left
              .brand
                = @title
            = render "menu/menu"

    .container.centered
      - if flash[:notice]
        .alert.alert-success
          = raw flash[:notice]
      - if flash[:error]
        .alert.alert-error
          = raw flash[:error]
    = yield
```

Then, I would like to have a different layout for every "module" specified in the controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :authorize
  load_and_authorize_resource
  layout 'user'
```

So I would like to have the following workflow :

page template (ex: /users/all)-> module layout (common elements for all /users/ pages) -> app layout (common elements for the whole app)

The first part (page template -> module layout) is extremly easy and is currently implemented. I just need to specify `layout 'user'` in the controller.

My question is : how can I tell "Don't render *only* the `user` layout but render the `application` layout too" ? I would like to have a layout of a layout.

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: may be you should create a third layout which have content of both layout . just an idea

Comment: Are you talking about nested layouts? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts

Comment: @phoet Thanks for the link, I'll try to follow the conventions.